# Monitoring service using Angular JS, http.get

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, monitor, http-get

I am trying to make a monitoring service of sorts using angular js. Basically, I understand how to do something like this.

```
$http.get('/my_service').success(function(data){
    $scope.my_data = data;
});
```

However, suppose that 'data' changes fairly frequently. How would I set things up such that I can monitor it (every 5 minutes or so, maybe more frequently), and update the data in the model when the data on my back end changes. Does angular js have anything for monitoring data? Would I just need to include the http.get request in some sort of loop with a timer? Really have no idea how to approach this one.

Comment: For the person who voted to close, I would request you actually be helpful and point me towards some resources that might help me, if you consider this question to broad for SO.

Comment: Look at using $inteval service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval